# Cannot connect component to redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In my profile page I have 3 cards, which means 3 react-components.

I am new to React.js and recently set up redux in my application. So the problem is two of them (cards) successfully connected to redux store, but third card can't for unknown reasons, can you help me please?

Redux store just returns `undefined` only for `Card3.js`

Hero.js (Profile)

```js
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
    import FadeIn from 'react-fade-in';
    import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
    import { Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'
    import { getUserProfile } from "../../services/user.service";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";

    import './profile.css'
    import LCard1 from "./cards/card1/LCard1"
    import Card1 from "./cards/card1/Card1"
    import Card2 from "./cards/card2/Card2"
    import Card3 from "./cards/card3/Card3"

    const Hero = (props) => {
        const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({username: ''})
        const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

        const getUser = async () => {
            console.log()
            await getUserProfile(props.uid)
                .then(res => {
                    setUserInfo(res)
                    setIsLoading(false)
                })

        }

        useEffect(() => {
            if (userInfo)
                getUser()
        }, [])

        return (
            <>
                <FadeIn transitionDuration={1000}>
                    {props.authenticated ? (
                        <section className="profile-cards">
                            <Container fluid >
                                <Row>
                                    {isLoading ? (
                                        <LCard1 />
                                    ) : (
                                        <Card1 user={userInfo} />
                                    )}
                                    <Card3 />
                                </Row>
                                <Row>
                                    <Card2 />
                                </Row>
                            </Container>
                        </section>  
                    ) : (
                        <Redirect to="/signin" />
                    )}
                </FadeIn>
            </>
        )
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
            uid: state.authReducer.uid,
            authenticated: state.authReducer.authenticated
        }
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
            logout: () => {
                dispatch({
                    type: 'SIGNOUT_SUCCESS'
                })
            }
        }
    }

    export default connect(
        mapStateToProps, 
        mapDispatchToProps
    )(Hero)
```

Card3.js

```js
    import React from 'react'
    import { connect } from "react-redux";

    import CreateAdvertisement from './content/create.advert/CreateAdvertisement'
    import MyMessages from './content/my.messages/MyMessages';
    import MySettings from './content/my.settings/MySettings';
    import MyVerfifcation from './content/my.verif/MyVerfifcation';

    import './card3.css'

    const Card3 = (props) => {
        
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Test: {props.username}</p>
                <section className="card3">
                    <div className="card3-box">
                        <div>
                            <MySettings />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        )
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
            key: state.authReducer.username
        }
    }

    export default connect(
        mapStateToProps
    )(Card3)
```

store.js

```js
    import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
    import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
    import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
    import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
    import reducers from './reducers/root.reducer'

    const persistConfig = {
        key: 'root',
        storage: storage,
        blacklist: ['sidebarReducer']
    }

    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers)

    const store = configureStore({
        reducer: persistedReducer,
        devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
        middleware: [thunk]
    })

    export default store
```

index.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './components/App'

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist'
import store from './store/store'

let persistor = persistStore(store)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text,ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './src/Redux/Store'
import MainNavigation from './src/components/Navigation/Navigation';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
           <MainNavigation/>
      </Provider>
      
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

First your all screens should under a navigation then

follow this code This will work for you Thanks.